# How to stored the selection of a radio button in a variable with PHP

Tags: php, radio-button

I'm trying to introduce the value selected out of a radio option with PHP into a variable so I can use the value.

Once the user has selected an option out of my radio (There are 5 options: 1 to 5) I'm trying to stored the value in a variable through PHP in the variable $rating and and then I tried to print the value of the variable twice, once in my PHP code with

```
echo $rating;
```

and once in my HTML with

```
<?php echo $rating;?>
```

But it doesn't print in either of the occasions, so I'm guessing I'm not able to store the value.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

```
<html>
<body>
    <?php
      if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
          $rating =  "";
          $rating = $_POST['rating'];
          echo $rating;

        <input type="radio" name="rating" value="1">
        <input type="radio" name="rating" value="2">
        <input type="radio" name="rating" value="3">
        <input type="radio" name="rating" value="4">
        <input type="radio" name="rating" value="5">

        <br>
        <?php echo $rating;?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: any form tags in there? If not, you need them. Give it a minute or two, someone's going to pop an answer for you ;-) or RTM in the meantime http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php *No better way to "learn"*.

Comment: Fred is correct, and please note that you don't need to check for the request method, just test if `$_POST['rating']` exist with `isset($_POST['rating'])`. And btw, you're missing the `if` `}` closing, and actually mixing HTML and PHP.

Comment: Also make sure you properly escape any user-supplied data before echoing it to the browser like that. i.e. do `echo htmlentities($rating);`. This prevents XSS attacks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Taking a few minutes to help you out*.

As I mentioned in comments, you need `<form></form>` tags in order to process POST arrays and a post method.

The following does that and makes use of PHP's ternary operator (*it's cleaner*) and `isset()`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>

<body>
    <?php
      if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

          $rating = $_POST['rating'];

}

?>

<?php 

$choice = "You chose: ";

    echo isset($rating) ? $choice.$rating : 'Make a selection';

?>

<form method = "post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>">

        <input type="radio" name="rating" value="1">
        <input type="radio" name="rating" value="2">
        <input type="radio" name="rating" value="3">
        <input type="radio" name="rating" value="4">
        <input type="radio" name="rating" value="5">

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

References:

- http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be incomplete. Although you are checking POST request method, there is not form for posting data through POST method.

```
<html>
<body>
    <?php
    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
        $rating =  "";
        $rating = $_POST['rating'];
        echo $rating;
    }
    else{
    ?>
    <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>"
        <input type="radio" name="rating" value="1">
        <input type="radio" name="rating" value="2">
        <input type="radio" name="rating" value="3">
        <input type="radio" name="rating" value="4">
        <input type="radio" name="rating" value="5">
        <input type="submit" name="submit">
        <br>
    </form>
    <?php } //end of 'if' statement ?>
</body>
</html>
```

[For reference on html form](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp)